# Python 3 threading and queueing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

I've been struggling with the concepts of threading, queuing, and passing data between two classes. I've searched on here and on the internet and haven't found anything that gives me what I need.

Basically I have some code that opens a gui in one thread and when you click start it opens another thread that counts.

The two biggest questions I have are:

1. How do you update the label in the GUI class to display the output of the Other class?
2. How do you stop the counting thread and restart it?

This is as far as I can get:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import queue
import time

class GUI(object):
    """GUI Object"""
    def __init__(self):        
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Window")

        self.root.status_lbl = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Label", width = 30)
        self.root.status_lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        self.root.start = tk.Button(self.root, text = "Start", width = 30, command = self.doing_things)
        self.root.start.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        self.root.stop = tk.Button(self.root, text = "Stop", width = 30, command = None)
        self.root.stop.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def doing_things(self):
        self.root.start.config(state = 'disabled')
        Other_thread = threading.Thread(None, Other)
        Other_thread.start()

class Other(object):
    """Something Else"""
    def __init__(self):   
        self.msg2 = "Other Thread"

        self.doing_things()

    def doing_things(self):
        count = 0
        while 1 == 1:
            count += 1
            data = (self.msg2 + " " + str(count))
            print(data)
            time.sleep(1)

GUI_thread = threading.Thread(None, GUI)

GUI_thread.start()
```

Any help would be great, this is driving me crazy.

UPDATE:

So this answers both of my questions and does pretty good:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import queue
import time

class GUI(object):
    """GUI Object"""
    def __init__(self):        
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Window")

        self.stop_flag = str

        self.status = tk.StringVar()
        self.status.set("plop")
        self.root.status_lbl = tk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.status, width = 30)
        self.root.status_lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        self.root.start = tk.Button(self.root, text = "Start", width = 30, command = self.doing_things)
        self.root.start.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        self.root.stop = tk.Button(self.root, text = "Stop", width = 30, command = self.stop)
        self.root.stop.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def doing_things(self):
        self.stop_flag = False
        self.root.start.config(state = 'disabled')
        Other_thread = threading.Thread(None, Other, args=(self,))
        Other_thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.root.start.config(state = 'normal')
        self.stop_flag = True


class Other(object):
    """Something Else"""
    def __init__(self, gui):
        self.count = 0

        self.gui = gui
        self.msg2 = "Other Thread"

        self.doing_things()

    def doing_things(self):
        count = self.count
        while not self.gui.stop_flag:
            count += 1
            data = (self.msg2 + " " + str(count))
            print(data)
            self.gui.status.set(data)
            time.sleep(1)

GUI_thread = threading.Thread(None, GUI)

GUI_thread.start()
```

The only thing that really confuses me is the need for the comma after self:

```
Other_thread = threading.Thread(None, Other, args=(self,))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way for changing the label from the other thread.
Use a StringVar instead of a fixed string. Then pass the GUI instance to the other thread when it's started. Finally you can set the text from the other thread.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import queue
import time

class GUI(object):
    """GUI Object"""
    def __init__(self):        
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Window")

        self.status = tk.StringVar()
        self.status.set("plop")
        self.root.status_lbl = tk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.status, width = 30)
        self.root.status_lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        self.root.start = tk.Button(self.root, text = "Start", width = 30, command = self.doing_things)
        self.root.start.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        self.root.stop = tk.Button(self.root, text = "Stop", width = 30, command = None)
        self.root.stop.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def doing_things(self):
        self.root.start.config(state = 'disabled')
        Other_thread = threading.Thread(None, Other, args=(self,))
        Other_thread.start()

class Other(object):
    """Something Else"""
    def __init__(self, gui):   
        self.gui = gui
        self.msg2 = "Other Thread"

        self.doing_things()

    def doing_things(self):
        count = 0
        while 1 == 1:
            count += 1
            data = (self.msg2 + " " + str(count))
            print(data)
            self.gui.status.set(data)
            time.sleep(1)

GUI_thread = threading.Thread(None, GUI)

GUI_thread.start()
```

Comment: That works perfectly, any idea on how to get the stop to work?

Comment: Never mind, now you pointed out how to change variables between threads I can just have the second thread's function run in a while loop based off of a variable set in the first thread.